# Detect if data in Oracle table has changed

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-performance

I'm looking for a best performance solution to detect if data in an Oracle table has changed. This will be used to kick start a calculation that uses lots of data from the same tables. It would be too expensive to poll the data to track changes. The changes happen rarely.

I have analyzed the following solutions to the problem.

- ORA_ROWSCN : Too slow, will do a full table scan.
- Oracle Audit : Not possible to set up in my environment.
- DBMS_ALERT : Writers are not able to signal.

Then I came up with the following simple idea. Add a trigger to the tables that increments a sequence on insert, update or delete. I know this will be materialized if rolled back but I can afford some false positives. My calculations service then polls the sequence current value to detect possible changes (= very cheap query)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_change_tracker
       before insert or update or delete on mytable
declare
    dummy number;
begin
     select seq_event_seqno.nextval into dummy from dual;
end;
```

How does this sound? Any pitfalls?

EDIT: Yes there is a major pitfall: When the writer holds back the commit, and the reader sees the new sequence value and query for changes before the writer has committed.

Comment: I would probably consider using the trigger only to capture the key/event and push it into a queue. That way you have minimal logic inside the trigger, and then you can have some other process "triggered" off the queue once items start showing up.

Comment: @Ditton, i have done what your describe before, but it is much less light weight. New tables to create, downgrading operations on audited tables, emptying queue-tables and beware not to delete events you haven't processed etc. I really like to get a solution to detect if a table has changed (not what has changed) as fast as possible.

Comment: managing a queue isn't that hard, if you're finding it that complex, you're not doing it right ;)   (you don't "delete" events yourself, you "dequeue" them .. ) if you only want to know IF it's changed, then just throw a single value/flag into the queue. In any case, if you don't want to play with queues, (I agree, there is a learning curve :) but it's worth it ) - then you're going to (potentially) spend a similar amount of energy on some other "makeshift" solution in any case.

Comment: Okay you are talking about true Oracle queues and not a table managed by a trigger?

Comment: I really like this solution of yours, for answering the specific question you posed. It's about as lightweight as you are going to get it. Just watch out for the sequence CACHE to understand the effects this might have between reads.

Comment: @TenG yes cache size must be 0

Comment: Depending on the process you're kicking off, might [database change notificaton](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm) or [continuous query notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_cqn.htm) work for you; or a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm) that does the actual calculation automatically rather than kick-starting something?

Comment: Doesn't your trigger solution (checking last_value) suffer from the same timing issue as kevinsky's timestamp answer? Thread 1 inserts and increments sequence; thread 2 inserts, increments sequence and commits;  your process sees the higher last_value and runs, picking up the thread 2 changes; thread 1 commits but last_value doesn't change again so those changes aren't seen? Actually, worse than that; last_value will change before *either* thread commits, so it can fail with a single thread?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks, you are so right. I thought the solution was elegant because sequences isn't transactional. But off course there is a race condition.

Comment: @Stig: re: "real" Queues vs "fake" queues - yes, of course ;)

Comment: I should have linked to the [data warehouse version of materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm). Your reference to a calculation suggests this might be appropriate; a materialized view log will track the changes for you, and a fast refresh MV will do the calculation. I may be oversimplifying your scenario though.

Comment: @AlexPoole, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652298/oracle-database-change-notification

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you some addition to your trigger soulution:
When your polling see changes of the sequence, you can check opened transactions on interested table, if it exists, then skip current recalc.

UPD:
Also, you can save min SCN of opened transactions, and in case of frequently table changes you will not freeze

UPD2:
It is some *heuristic improvement*, not full problem solution. If you will skip recal every time when you see opened transaction, then you can freeze much time in case of frequently (and may be long) DML on table.
I mean, when seq is changed and the polling see opened transactions on your table, you can store `min(start_scn)` from v$transaction, and when the polling see opened transactions at next time you can compare current `min(start_scn)` with sotred `min(start_scn)`, if current is greater then it is *some* chance that it is time to recalc.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the use of SCN?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( for particular XTABLE ):

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tab_modifications WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XTABLE';
```

it will allow you ( among other data ) to see:

```
INSERTS UPDATES DELETES
43,708  1,845   0
```

.. there are issues ( bugs in some Oracle versions ), but if you will test thoroughly in your environment - you may find this useful.

.. as this question is pretty old - it would be nice to know how you implemented the change detection mechanism.

Comment: I ended up using Continuous Query Notification (CQN) combined with a full re-calculation every hour. I had cases where the notification did not publish as expected, but mostly in was running fine (publish-subscribe is a hard problem to solve due to network errors, timeout etc)

Comment: I do not think that a Oracle has any guarantees to when dba_tab_modifications is updated, so this could be dangerous to use this.